# Ошибка в Qt creator 6.0.2

Tags: c++, qt, эмулятор

Ошибка из-за эмулятора можно ли её решить и как мне подключить телефон(не с эмулятора) в qt по проводу не нашел соответствующих кнопок и информации в интернете(я нашел информации, но связанную с qt 4). Заранее спасибо(мучаюсь с ошибкой уже неделю)

[image: картинка самой ошибки]

[image: все ошибки]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: сделайте всё это сначала в Android Studio, если не особенно разбираетесь в java возьмите готовый пример